# Use circuitikz voltage source icon as a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm using circuitikz to draw a single line diagram:

[image: Output]

But I have no idea how to get rid of the line on top of the voltage source. Is there a simple way to do it?

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (15,20);
    \draw (2,18) to [sV] (2,16); %voltage source
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,16) node[anchor=south]{b1} -- (3,16);
    \draw (1.5,16) -- (1.5,13);
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,13) node[anchor=south]{b3} -- (3,13);
    \draw(2.5,13) |- +(0,0.5) -- +(4,0.5) |- +(4,0);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,13) node[anchor=south]{b4} -- +(2,0);
    \draw (7.5,13) -- (7.5,16);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,16) node[anchor=south]{b2} -- +(2,0);
    \draw(6.5,16) |- +(0,-0.5) -- +(-4,-0.5) |- +(-4,-0);
    \draw (2,16) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (2,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (7,16) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (7,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};

    \draw (2.3,12.4)--(3,12) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Load}};
    \draw (2.3,17.4)--(3,18) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Fixed voltage}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Voltage source is a bipole component. It will have two connections generally. Are you sure that you want only one connection?

Comment: yep. That's definitely the way I'd draw it for most cases, but for a HV distribution network, I'm simply using it to represent a fixed voltage. A quick [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=distribution+network+single-line+diagram&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi) indicates that either practice is acceptable.

Comment: I'm an electrical engineer and I strongly disagree with you that "either practice is acceptable", I would consider a single ended voltage source to be an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw the voltage source for a length that is equal to the diameter of the circle! And connect it separately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    %\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (15,20);
    \draw (2,17.85) to [sV] (2,17); %voltage source
    \draw (2,17) -- (2,16); %% Connecting the voltage source.
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,16) node[anchor=south]{b1} -- (3,16);
    \draw (1.5,16) -- (1.5,13);
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,13) node[anchor=south]{b3} -- (3,13);
    \draw(2.5,13) |- +(0,0.5) -- +(4,0.5) |- +(4,0);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,13) node[anchor=south]{b4} -- +(2,0);
    \draw (7.5,13) -- (7.5,16);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,16) node[anchor=south]{b2} -- +(2,0);
    \draw(6.5,16) |- +(0,-0.5) -- +(-4,-0.5) |- +(-4,-0);
    \draw (2,16) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (2,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (7,16) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};
    \draw (7,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon, rotate=180, regular polygon sides=3,minimum size=0.8,draw]{};

    \draw (2.3,12.4)--(3,12) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Load}};
    \draw (2.3,17.4)--(3,18) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Fixed voltage}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I was having trouble with that approach before, but the problem was that I was using `\draw (2,17.1) to [sV] (2,17);`, which was too short a distance. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, less hacky :)

Every bipole has an underlying node shape, whose name is something like xxxshape. Most are easy to infer (`resistorshape`, for instance), but the rest must be looked up in `pgfcircbipoles.sty`. In this case, it is `vsourcesinshape`.

If you update to the new version of the package (I just posted it a few days ago), you can also use the new ground, `sground`.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (2,17) node[vsourcesinshape, rotate=90] (V1) {}
          (V1.left) -- (2,15.5) node[sground]{};
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,16) node[anchor=south]{b1} -- (3,16);
    \draw (1.5,16) -- (1.5,13);
    \draw [ultra thick] (1,13) node[anchor=south]{b3} -- (3,13);
    \draw(2.5,13) |- +(0,0.5) -- +(4,0.5) |- +(4,0);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,13) node[anchor=south]{b4} -- +(2,0);
    \draw (7.5,13) -- (7.5,16);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,16) node[anchor=south]{b2} -- +(2,0);
    \draw(6.5,16) |- +(0,-0.5) -- +(-4,-0.5) |- +(-4,-0);
    \draw (0,-0.5) ;
    \draw (2,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[sground]{};
    \draw (7,16) -- +(0,-0.5) node[sground]{};
    \draw (7,13) -- +(0,-0.5) node[sground]{};

    \draw (2.3,12.4)--(3,12) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Load}};
    \draw (2.3,17.4)--(3,18) [anchor= west] node{\emph{Fixed voltage}};

\end{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to simply add this to your code

```

```
\draw [white,thick](2,17.997)--(2,17.434)       ;   % covers unwanted line
\draw[gray,very thin](2,17.997)--(2,17.434)     ;   % matches with background
```

```