# Electric network one-line diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuits

I'm looking for a way of drawing [one-line diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-line_diagram) of power distribution grids. So far I've come across CircuiTikZ, but this package seems to be oriented to a different kind of circuit diagram and doesn't include basic components such as buses. Does anyone know of a package that I could use for this?

Here is an example of such a diagram:

[image: Aufnahmefähigkeit von Niederspannungsverteilnetzen für die Einspeisung aus Photovoltaikkleinanlagen - Georg Kerber]

Comment: Please post a photo of such a diagram!

Comment: Did you take a look at `pst-circ`?

Comment: I had not but it does seem better than CircuiTikZ for my purposes.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87275/use-circuitikz-voltage-source-icon-as-a-node could be a start.

Answer (score 1):

I work with Power Systems and I like LaTex. For many years, I searched a properly lib for draw one-line diagrams including power transmission lines, power transformers, generators, motors, loads, instrument transformers, etc. But until now, without success. I use [Circuit Macros](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/) that uses M4 macros pre-processor to generate a .pic file and then dpic (or gpic) to generate a .tex file. It is not properly for Power Systems, but it helps.

Example code:

```
% `Loop.m4'
.PS
cct_init
ifdef(`AND_gate',,`include(liblog.m4)')
xgap = 0.6
define(`dimen_',0.75)
dim1 = 1; dim2 = 0.75 ; dim3=0.5
P0 : Here
box fill_(0.9) wid 1 "Xingu" "\SI{500}{\kV}"
P01 : Here
move to P0
move down 0.4
"$R_0=\SI{1,682}{\ohm}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here ljust
move to P01
source(right_ dim2, G); llabel(,YY,); rlabel(,18~\%,)
P1 : Here
move down 0.2
line thick 3*linethick up 0.4 
move up 0.1
"$s$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here
move to P1
move right 0.1
move down 0.1
arrow right 0.2
move down 0.1
move left 0.2
"$I^s$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here
move to P1
move right 1.5
move up 0.1
"$l=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here
move to P1
line right 3.0
P2 : Here
move down 0.2
line thick 3*linethick up 0.4 
move up 0.1
"$r$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here
move to P2
source(right_ dim2, G); llabel(,YY,); rlabel(,18~\%,)
P3 : Here
box fill_(0.9) wid 1 "Nova Igua\c{c}u" "\SI{500}{\kV}"
move to P3
move down 0.4
"$Z_0=a+b$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here ljust
move to P1
move right 0.6
move up  0.3
RELE : BOX_gate(PP,,,,21)
line left 0.15 from last [].In1
move left 0.1
"$V^s$"
line left 0.15 from last [].In2
move left 0.1
"$I^s$"
move to P1
move right 0.2
move down 0.2
"$R_0=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here ljust
move to P1
move right 2.8
move down 0.2
"$R_0=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at Here rjust
.PE
```

Using M4 macros and dpic according to manual is possible to generate a .tex file for generate the following figure (I did few changes in the .tex file, modifying some text).

[image]

I want to write a lib for Power Systems to including in Circuit Macros.

Answer (score 1):

For interest, here is [Renzo Fabián](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321897/95441)'s code without all those `move`s:

```
.PS
log_init
xgap = 0.6
define(`dimen_',0.75)
  dim1 = 1; dim2 = 0.75 ; dim3=0.5
  X: box fill_(0.9) wid 1 "Xingu" "\SI{500}{\kV}"
  { "$R_0=\SI{1,682}{\ohm}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at X.sw below ljust }
  source(right_ dim2, G); llabel(,YY,); rlabel(,18~\%,)
  { B1: line thick 3*linethick up 0.4 with .c at Here
    "$s$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 }
  { arrow right 0.2 from last line.c+(0.1,-0.1) }
  { "$I^s$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at last line.start below }
  line right 3.0 "$l=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 above
  { B2: line thick 3*linethick up 0.4 with .c at Here
    "$r$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 above }
  source(right_ dim2, G); llabel(,YY,); rlabel(,18~\%,)
  NI: box fill_(0.9) wid 1 "Nova Igua\c{c}u" "\SI{500}{\kV}"
  "$Z_0=a+b$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at NI.sw below ljust
  RELE : BOX_gate(PP,,,,) with .w at B1+(0.6,0.3)
  line left 0.15 from last [].In1
  "$V^s$" rjust
  line left 0.15 from last [].In2
  "$I^s$" rjust
  "$R_0=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at B1+(0.2,-0.2) ljust
  "$R_0=\SI{2600}{\km}$" wid 0.1 ht 0.1 at B1+(2.8,-0.2) rjust
.PE
```