# Electrical grid using circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to draw this using circuitikz but I'm having some troubles specially in doing the "busbars", the Voltage source not being connected to anything on its east and putting 2 arrows in a branch.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with what you've tried so far? It'll help lay the foundation to get you answers quicker.

Comment: You can look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87275/use-circuitikz-voltage-source-icon-as-a-node.

Comment: Would you mind at least state the names of these components?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.21,-2.70) rectangle (7.08,5.76);
\draw [line width=1.6pt] (-1.,0.)-- (0.,0.);
\draw(-2.,0.) circle (1.cm);
\draw [line width=4.4pt] (0.,1.)-- (0.,-1.);
\draw (0.,0.65)-- (0.5,0.65);
\draw (0.5,0.65)-- (3.9,3.52);
\draw (3.91,3.52)-- (3.91,4.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0.,-0.65)-- (4.08,-0.65);
\draw (4.08,-0.65)-- (4.08,-1.21);
\draw (5.,4.01)-- (5.,-1.21);
\draw [line width=4.4pt] (3.69,4.00)-- (5.30,4.00);
\draw [line width=4.4pt] (3.70,-1.21)-- (5.32,-1.20);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (4.5,4.00) -- (4.5,5.1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (4.56,-1.21) -- (4.56,-2.21);
\draw (-2.44,0.3) node[anchor=north west] {\Huge $\mathbf{\sim}$};
\draw (-0.18,1.6) node[anchor=north west] {$1$};
\draw (4.36,-0.22) node[anchor=north west] {$2$};
\draw (4.24,3.7) node[anchor=north west] {$3$};
\draw (-0.37,-1.1) node[anchor=north west] {$V_1$};
\draw (0.56,-0.80) node[anchor=north west] {$P_{12}$};
\draw (2.77,-0.80) node[anchor=north west] {$Q_{12}$};
\draw (5.79,4.56) node[anchor=north west] {$V_1$};
\draw (5.86,-0.55) node[anchor=north west] {$V_2$};
\draw (1.34,1.3) node[anchor=north west] {$P_{13}$};
\draw (3.35,2.90) node[anchor=north west] {$Q_{31}$};
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (1.09,0.84) -- (2.12,1.70);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (3.8,3.1) -- (2.76,2.27);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (0.34,-0.84) -- (1.5,-0.84);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (3.7,-0.82) -- (2.4,-0.82);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```