# What would be the tikz code for this particular voltage source?

Tags: circuitikz

I am using circuitikz and I cannot find the code for this particular voltage source. It is a sinusoidal source with the polarity + and - on its ends, inside the circle.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also do a search for e.g. "Voltage source" on this site and study the results (there are numerous hits and in at least one I see the sine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336498/electrical-grid-using-circuitikz).

Comment: @albert Actually I am new to circuitikz. and I just copy-pasted the circuit above from my textbook. We have to do an exercise from the textbook so I try to make a LaTeX document and I couln't find the appropiate circuitikz code for the voltage source used in my textbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following defines a new symbol for `circuitikz` called `sVpm` (for **sV** **p**lus and **m**inus) which you can use inside of a circuit. It's just a copy of the definition of `sinusoidal voltage source` combined with the one of `american voltage source`, with a few parameters slightly tweaked.

It also provides a variation to be used for horizontal output called `sVpmh`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{sVpm}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/width}}{

  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}     
      \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\scriptsize$-$}
      \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{\scriptsize$+$}

    \pgf@circ@res@up = .35\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgfscope
      \pgftransformrotate{90}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@up}{0cm}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\def\pgf@circ@sVpm@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{sVpm}{#1}}
\compattikzset{sinusoidal voltage source pm/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@sVpm@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=true, v=#1 }}
\compattikzset{sVpm/.style = {\comnpatname sinusoidal voltage source pm = #1}}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{sVpmh}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/width}}{

  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}     
      \pgftext[center,x=0.2\pgf@circ@res@down-\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\scriptsize$-$}
      \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{\scriptsize$+$}

    \pgf@circ@res@up = .35\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgfscope
      \pgftransformrotate{90}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@up}{0cm}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\def\pgf@circ@sVpmh@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{sVpmh}{#1}}
\compattikzset{sinusoidal voltage source pmh/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@sVpmh@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=true, v=#1 }}
\compattikzset{sVpmh/.style = {\comnpatname sinusoidal voltage source pmh = #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) to[sVpmh] (2,0) to[sVpm] (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Another horizontal variant which not only turns the minus sign but also rotates the sinusoidal wave and does some space and size adjustments:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{sVpm}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/width}}{

  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}     
  \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=0.1\pgf@circ@res@down+\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\scriptsize$-$}
  \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=0.1\pgf@circ@res@up+\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{\scriptsize$+$}

    \pgf@circ@res@up = .3\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgfscope
      \pgftransformrotate{90}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@up}{0cm}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\def\pgf@circ@sVpm@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{sVpm}{#1}}
\compattikzset{sinusoidal voltage source pm/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@sVpm@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=true, v=#1 }}
\compattikzset{sVpm/.style = {\comnpatname sinusoidal voltage source pm = #1}}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{sVpmh}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourcesin/width}}{

  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}     
      \pgftext[center,x=0.1\pgf@circ@res@down-\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\scriptsize$-$}
      \pgftext[center,x=-0.1\pgf@circ@res@down+\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\scriptsize$+$}

    \pgf@circ@res@up = .3\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgfscope
      %\pgftransformrotate{90}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@up}{0cm}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{-.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\def\pgf@circ@sVpmh@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{sVpmh}{#1}}
\compattikzset{sinusoidal voltage source pmh/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@sVpmh@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=true, v=#1 }}
\compattikzset{sVpmh/.style = {\comnpatname sinusoidal voltage source pmh = #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) to[sVpmh] (2,0) to[sVpm] (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you very much! And I use a label to write the vs(t)=Vm.cos(Wt), right?

Comment: @marmot honestly I have no idea how to do that with low-level `pgf`. Would be great to see how to do that. Feel free to take my answer and improve it in any way :)

Comment: You are already using ` \pgftransformrotate{90}`, which is all you need to rotate stuff. One way to go would be to introduce a pgfkey for that, which introduces an additional rotation, and the user can set as (s)he likes. (I do not post answers to answered questions, especially when the existing answer(s) is/are good and accepted. ;-))

Comment: @marmot I thought of/wished for something automatic (so how to find out whether it is used horizontally or vertically). But if you don't know how to do it, I'll maybe post an edit later or tomorrow with a horizontal variant.

Comment: @marmot Please would you mind telling where I should put the `\pgftransformrotate{90}` in order to create a horizontal variant?

Comment: @mandresybilly there already is a horizontal variant. Do you want the sinusoidal signal turned, too? That won't fit that easy, you'd have to also reduce the size and move the plus and minus.

Comment: @mandresybilly funny thing: In that case you don't have to add a `\pgftransformrotate` but remove it :)